# Is there a way to copy from ubunt to windows? like a command or feature I can install?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, keyboard

So right now I'm running into two problems in windows:

1) Is there a way to connect the keyboard from windows to ubuntu virtual box? Because if I copy something in windows and right now I can't paste into ubuntu, and vice versa, do I need to install a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the Guest Additions?  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

> the Guest Additions are designed to be installed inside a virtual machine after the guest operating system has been installed ... Shared clipboard
>       With the Guest Additions installed, the clipboard of the guest operating system can optionally be shared with your host operating system;

Comment: thank you sir, I remember last year my dad showed me a command that can "connect" the keyboard between ubuntu and windows, and it worked. But now I reinstalled the virtual box, I don't think I left out anything?